# Anim folder is not coming

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

In my android Project, I need to create an 'anim' folder. As most people know, the anim folder will be used to store animations.

1. How do I create a folder?
2. Where does the anim folder belong?

Comment: you should create anim folder.

Comment: wow, this is a real *facetable* question...

Comment: Right click on the `res folder` -> New -> Folder -> create a folder named `anim`. Simple. ;-)

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html. Should check the doc

Comment: Android studio does not have the concept of a "Folder", it instead calls that a "Directory" in the right-click menu for New.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to create a new folder right click on res folder create new folder name it anim. And you can put your animation xmls in it.

Comment: Thank you for also adding where the folder belongs.

Comment: Thanks, I take it you mean "create new resource directory"

Comment: Just to add ever example (including on stackoverflow) just state "create anim directory" and that's it. Good to know where.

Answer (score 4):

In the Android application default folder structure there is no Anim folder. If you want Anim folder, you should be create it in to the application.